# Pop Up success mesg doesn't work for me

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a simple e_form with insertion button, I wanna add pop up message if the insertion process succeed, I add it alone and it works but when combining it with my code I got an error.

my code is

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // connection stuff...
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TextBox5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_no", TextBox2.Text);
    int result;
    result=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if result >0
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
         "script", "<script>data has been added successfully</script>");            
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you add the exact error you get so we don't have to guess. You might want to read [ask] to see what we expect from questions.

Comment: sorry for confusion, it didn't generate an error , the pop up mesg never showed up after the insertion process

Comment: You should at least have a compile error for the code snippet you shared and the Developer console of your browser should have complained as well. Including that kind of info is crucial to have a question that is also useful for others. Please use the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) before you post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check few things before executing the SQL query.
i)are your html DOM elements are populated as soon as the page because RegisterStartupScript method places javascript at the bottom of the page just before closing of the  element.
ii)is our ExecuteNonQuery returning result.
RegisterStartupScript (type type,string key,string script,bool addtags) is mostly used for scripts that must run on page load but your code must run on image button click,so use below method

```
int result = 1;
if (result==1)
 { 
 ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"script", "alert('data has been added successfully');", true);
 }
```

This should work..Cheers

Comment: thanks , I tried this and it works .... thumbs up    int result; 
          result=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          if (result>=1)
          {
              string jscript = "<script>alert('تم اضافة البيانات بنجاح')</script>";
              System.Type t = this.GetType();
              ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(t, "k", jscript);
          }

Answer (score 0):

The if requires brackets

```
if(result > 0)
```

I would also suggest adding a label or alert. The `,true` adds the  tags

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
         "script", "alert('data has been added successfully');", true);
```

Comment: Hmmm , it didn't work also, the pop up does not appear